# What is the most efficient way to test for duplicates in a user inputted array?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, duplicates, user-input

I am trying to write a simulator for playing the *Powerball lottery*, where the program would ask for `5` numbers (aka the white balls) and be inputted into a `6` element array and another number (the red Powerball) into the `6`th element.
I need to figure out how to test for duplicates in the first `5` elements but the `6`th doesn't need to be unique.

I have a loop that I thought would work but it doesn't even execute and is rather messy.

Is there a more efficient way to test for duplicates, maybe involving a bool flag?

```
const int PBALLAMOUNT = 6;
const int PBMAX = 69;
const int PBMIN = 1;
const int REDMAX = 26;

cout << "Enter the numbers you want to use for the white powerballs" << endl;
for (int k = 0; k < PBALLAMOUNT - 1; k++)
{
    cin >> pBallNums[k];
    while (pBallNums[k] < PBMIN || pBallNums[k]>PBMAX) 
    {
        cout << "Invalid input! Please enter different numbers between 1 and 69" << endl;
        cin >> pBallNums[k];
    }
}

bool dup = false;
for (int i = 0; i < PBALLAMOUNT - 1; i++) 
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < PBALLAMOUNT - 1; j++) 
    {
        while (!dup) 
        {
            if (pBallNums[i] == pBallNums[j]) 
            {
                cout << "Please enter a unique number from the others in your PowerBall number selection" << endl;
                cin >> pBallNums[i];
            }

        }
    }
}

cout << "And what would you like for your redball" << endl;
cin >> pBallNums[5];

while (pBallNums[5] < PBMIN || pBallNums[5] > REDMAX)
{
    cout << " The red powerball needs to be between 1 and 26: ";
    cin >> pBallNums[5];
}
```

I basically just need it to alert the user if they have already entered a number into the array and offer another `std::cin >> pBallNums` statement but the actual result is just nothing happens after you enter the numbers.

Comment: What is `pBallNums`? An array or an `std::vector`? And does the order of the values in `pBallNums` matter?

Comment: [std::any_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) (and friends) seem like an obvious tool to reach for..

Comment: Consider using a `std::set`. All items in the set are guaranteed unique.

Comment: Surprised by the upvotage the `set` comment received. For a list of at most size 4 @JesperJuhl 's pitch is going to be much more efficient

Comment: @user4581301 Your comment made me benchmark the two cases. It turned out that both of them have the same effect in terms of efficiency. **[See here](http://quick-bench.com/cgruRLzPss62dkDEJk7LRmj51Kg)**

Comment: @JeJo Neat site. Going to have to play with that later. All I see is that both execute too fast for the benchmark. For a few entries run once that's to be expected.

Answer (score 3):

> "I basically just need it to alert the user if they've already entered
>   a number into the array and offer another `cin >> pBallNums` statement."

In that case simply use **[`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)** and use it's **[`std::set::emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/emplace)** method to store the user input into the set.

From *[cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set)*,

```
template< class... Args >
std::pair<iterator,bool> emplace( Args&&... args );
```

> **`std::set::emplace`**
>
> Returns a pair consisting of an iterator to the inserted element, or the already-existing element **if no insertion**
>   **happened, and a bool denoting whether the insertion took place**. True
>   for Insertion, **False for No Insertion**.

Simply take this information for your case and loop again for the next user input.

---

Here is a sample code **([See Live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CScnB7sw6uv4bZFF))**:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <set>

int main()
{
    std::set<int> mySet;

    for(int loopCount{ 0 }; loopCount != 5; )// repeat until maximum loop count
    {
        int input; std::cin >> input; // user input
        // get the std::pair<iterator,bool>
        const auto pairIter = mySet.emplace(input);
        // increment maximum loop count, if insertion successful
        if (pairIter.second) ++loopCount;
    }
    for (const int userInput : mySet)
        std::cout << userInput << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

**Sample input**:

```
1
1
2
3
4
2
4
3
5
```

**Output**:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Sort, then check adjacent items for equality.

Answer (score 1):

First, try not to mix real requirements with implementation details.

> [...] where the program would ask for 5 numbers (aka the white balls)
>   and be inputted into a 6 element array and another number (the red
>   powerball) into the 6th element.

What you really want is: 5 distinct numbers taken from user input. And from your code I read that the check should happen after each single input. I suppose reading the last number is fine, so lets leave that aside.

Next, get acustomed to the [containers in the standard library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container). They are not many in numbers but what you can do with them is uncountable. To have distinct elements in a container you want either [`std::unsorted_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set) or [`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set). 
Then basically all you need is to use [`insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert):

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::set<int> numbers;
    auto x = numbers.insert(1);
    std::cout << "1 was not present before? : " << x.second << "\n";
    x = numbers.insert(1);
    std::cout << "1 was not present before? : " << x.second << "\n";
}
```

prints:

```
1 was not present before? : 1
1 was not present before? : 0
```