# How to alert a user if the number they entered into a 1 dimensional array has already been entered?

Tags: c++, arrays

Ok so I'm trying to write a program that will accept 5 distinct numbers from the user and would input into a 6 element one dimensional array and then be tested to make sure that its between 1 and 69 and that the number (just entered) isn't already in the array.

I've already tested for the range issue but I cant figure out how to test the duplicate array issue because the tester executes regardless of what the numbers are or just not at all.

Also just in case anyone is wondering any kind of "pball" variable is related to the powerball lottery, this is just one function of several In a powerball simulator. As much as I want to I cant use library functions (like sort) due to requirements by my professor.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int PBALLAMOUNT = 6;
const int PBMAX = 69;
const int PBMIN = 1;

int pBallNums[PBALLAMOUNT];



void pBallInput(int pBallNums[PBALLAMOUNT]) {

cout << "Enter the numbers you want to use." << endl;

    for (int k = 0; k < PBALLAMOUNT - 1; k++) {
        cin >> pBallNums[k];

        while (pBallNums[k] < PBMIN || pBallNums[k]>PBMAX) {

            cout << "Invalid input! Please enter different numbers between 1 and 69" << endl;
            cin >> pBallNums[k];
        }
            for (int qt = 0; qt < PBALLAMOUNT; qt++)
                while (pBallNums[qt] == pBallNums[qt + 1]) {
                    cout << " you need 5 unique numbers. Please enter a new number ";
                     cin >> pBallNums[qt];
                }
        }
}
```

when I execute the current code, the repeat test displays regardless. it should only display if the number your trying to enter has already been put put into the array.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look into [`std::unordered_set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set).

Comment: You should get together with the asker of [this linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56029286/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-test-for-duplicates-in-a-user-inputted-array). Two heads are better than one.

Answer (score 0):

```
            for (int qt = 0; qt < PBALLAMOUNT; qt++)
                while (pBallNums[qt] == pBallNums[qt + 1]) {
                 // stuff not changing qt
                }
```

You have an endless `while` loop within that `for` loop.  The outer `for` loop isn't iterating, it's just the inner `while` loop.

---

(if the order of input doesn't matter, then use a `std::set` or even better `std::unordered_set`)

Apart from that, I think you should try to organize your code better.  Use small functions for small tasks!

```
while (/* not all numbers set */)
{
  // input number here
  if (/* input failed */)
  {
    // handle IO failure; best to exit probably
  }
  else if (/* input not in correct range */)
  {
    // print error, retry
  }
  else if (/* input number already present in array */)
  {
     // print error, retry
  }
  else
  {
     // save input to current array index
     // advance current array index if you need more numbers
  }
}

// Implement this for the check above
// size == numbers read so far
bool input_already_present(int * array, size_t size, int number);
```